How to adjust the x ticks axis to whole numbers in vega lite
`{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "params": [
{
  "name": "_normal_height_coefficient",
  "value": 7000,
  "bind": {
    "input": "range",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 800,
    "step": 10,
    "name": "Height Coefficient: "
  }
},
{
  "name": "_normal_mean",
  "value": 5,
  "bind": {
    "input": "range",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 10,
    "step": 0.5,
    "name": "Mean: "
  }
},
{
  "name": "_normal_std_dev",
  "value": 1,
  "bind": {
    "input": "range",
    "min": 0,
    "max": 3,
    "step": 0.5,
    "name": "Standard Deviation: "
  }
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
{
  "name": "NORMAL_DISTRIBUTION",
  "width": 960,
  "height": 710,
  "data": {
    "sequence": {
      "start": 0,
      "stop": 10,
      "step": 0.1,
      "as": "_x_normal"
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "densityNormal( datum['_x_normal'], _normal_mean, _normal_std_dev )",
      "as": "_y_base"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "2.5 * _normal_height_coefficient",
      "as": "_y_factor"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum['_y_base'] * datum['_y_factor']",
      "as": "_y_normal"
    }
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "area",
    "color": "#E3E3E3"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "_x_normal",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "_y_normal",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "HISTOGRAM",
  "mark": {
    "type": "bar",
    "color": "#0F4C81",
    "opacity": 0.7,
    "tooltip": true
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "bin": {"step": 1},
      "field": "TouchCount",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Touch Count",
      "scale": {"domain": [0, 10]}
    },
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "count",
      "title": "Count"
    }
  }
}
  ]
}`

Hi Experts,
I want the mean of normal distribution chart to be mean of TouchCount field by default. I don't want user to select anything. Currently user possible to select Mean, Standard deviation and Height of the chart. Also, there is lot of space in the right side when I change the filter for example when I try to change the date filter to fewer months. Then, there is only 2 touchcounts, But, I want it to show always 10 touchcounts without space on the right side.

Can you share sample code with data, like the example here:
"data": {"values": [{"date": "2024-02-15", "amount": 20, "value": 100},{"date": "2024-05-15", "amount": 40, "value": 90}]} 
This will allow answering your question
